# Get facebook user's profile picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my php code to get Facebook user profile image when I have logged in using facebook in my website. But photos is not displaying. I am getting a broken image.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid', 'appcode');
$facebook = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.com/index.php/');


try 
{
    if($session = $facebook->getSessionFromRedirect()) 
    {
        $_SESSION['facebook'] = $session->getToken();
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook'])) 
   {
        $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
        $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $request = $request->execute();
        $user = $request->getGraphObject(Facebook\GraphUser::className());
        echo "Name: " . $user->getName();
        echo "<br/>";

        echo '<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/". $user. /picture?type=large\">';

    }
}

    catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) 
    {

      echo " Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }  
    catch(\Exception $e) 
      {

      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following Graph path via GET request:

```
/{user_id}?fields=picture.type(large),id,name
```

Field **type** can be one of the following values:

- small
- normal
- large
- square

Or using width and/or height value like this:

```
/{user_id}?fields=picture.width(200).height(200),id,name
```

Also you can add **redirect=0** param.
By default the picture edge will return a picture instead of a JSON response. If you want the picture edge to return JSON that describes the image set redirect=0 when you make the request.

So you will have JSON response:

```
{
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 120,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c53.10.120.120/165675_138088076251005_752993_n.jpg?oh=a9450bf53f2d2294531e11ae28be99c1&oe=56C740A5",
      "width": 120
    }
  },
  "id": "138087416251071",
  "name": "Zenonis",
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you set up a Facebook app, you have an "App ID" and an "App Secret" (which you specify as 'ID' and 'Code').

You can use both these variables to get a user's picture with the following url:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/' . $user_id . '/picture?redirect=0&type=large&access_token=' . $app_id . '|' . $app_secret;
```

You can then print this url out in an  src attribute:

```
<img src="<?php print $url; ?>" />
```

Comment: Wow, what a bad answer – how did this stand so long without anyone saying something? What you are suggesting would leak your app secret/app access token to anyone who visits that page – which is of course something one should never do. Profile pictures can be requested without any access token. (If one wants to use an access token, to avoid running into API limits if a lot of profile pictures are to be displayed, then one should use a user access token for the user that is currently using the app.)

Comment: @CBroe good point. Can't remember the context of why I thought this was right but you are absolutely correct.